# Vaadin 7 Grid Editor click

Tags: java, grid, click, editor, vaadin7

After enabling grid editing, I would like to be able to call a method that opens a window on the screen. Is it possible to create an event after clicking on the table field while editing? Alternatively, can I add a button or something that will trigger an event?

Answer (score 2):

It's been quite a while, but in case this question is still relevant for anybody, you can add your own field implementations to the editor via `grid.getColumn("columnId").setEditorField(myField)`, but only for the existing columns. Neither `Button` nor `PopupView` implement `Field`, of course, so if you want to use either you'd need to wrap it into a `CustomField`.

If you have any actions that you'd like to use outside of the editor you could also try [GridActionRenderer](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gridactionrenderer-add-on/) add-on, and then add your `CustomField` to the actions column in the editor (there is no default implementation for using the actions from the editor).